# Fazer Lista Par e Impar

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Fiz um código onde o usuário vai inserir uma quantidade ilimitada de números em uma lista dinâmica encadeada até que digite 0 e pare a inserção, mostrando no final, todos os números digitados pelo usuário. Agora quero verificar os valores inseridos pelo o usuário e dividí-los em uma lista de números pares e outra lista de números impares. Alguém consegue me ajudar a desenrolar o restante desse código?

código que fiz até agora:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ponto{
    int num;
    struct ponto * proximo; //PONTEIRO PARA O PRÓXIMO ELEMENTO
}t_ponto; //QUANDO FOR DECLARAR UMA VARIÁVEL NÃO SERÁ PRECISO DECLARAR TODO O "STRUCT", BASTA DECLARAR O t_ponto


int main (){
    
    t_ponto * ini_ponto; //PONTEIRO QUE MARCA O INÍCIO DA LISTA
    t_ponto * proximo_ponto; //PONTEIRO QUE MARCA O PRÓXIMO PONTEIRO DA LISTA
    
    int resp; //VARIÁVEL PARA COLETAR A RESPOSTA DO USUÁRIO
    ini_ponto = (t_ponto *) malloc (sizeof(t_ponto)); //ALOCANDO A MEMÓRIA
    
    if(ini_ponto == NULL){ //TESTANDO SE A LISTA ESTÁ VAZIA
        exit(1);
    };
    
    proximo_ponto = ini_ponto; //PRÓXIMO PONTO ESTÁ AGORA APONTANDO PARA O INÍCIO DA LISTA
    
    while(1){
        
        printf("Digite um numero para inserir na lista: ");
        scanf("%d", &proximo_ponto->num); //A VARIÁVEL DE UMA STRUCT É ACESSADA ATRAVÉS DA "->" 
        
        printf("Deseja continuar? <1> SIM <0> NAO: ");
        scanf("%d", &resp);
        
        if(resp == 1){
            proximo_ponto->proximo = (t_ponto *) malloc (sizeof(t_ponto)); //AQUI ESTAMOS ALOCANDO A MEMÓRIA PARA O PRÓXIMO ELEMENTO
            proximo_ponto = proximo_ponto->proximo;
        } else
            break;
        
    }

    
    printf("\n");
    
    proximo_ponto->proximo = NULL; //DIZENDO QUE A LISTA CHEGOU AO FIM, CASO O USUÁRIO NÃO QUEIRA MAIS INSERIR NÚMEROS
    proximo_ponto = ini_ponto; //APONTANDO PARA O INÍCIO DA LISTA PARA COMEÇAR A LISTÁ-LA.
    
    while(proximo_ponto != NULL){
        printf("Os valores da lista original sao: %d;\n", proximo_ponto->num);
        proximo_ponto = proximo_ponto->proximo;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas é para inserir logo em duas listas diferentes ou tem que inserir tudo numa lista para depois dividir em duas ?

Answer (score -1):

Crie duas listas. Uma para números pares e uma para números ímpares.

Depois percorra a sua lista com o for e testa dentro dela se um número é par ou ímpar.

Você pode fazer isso dividindo o número por 2 e pegando o resto da divisão. Se o resto da divisão for igual a 1, significa que o número é ímpar.

Exemplo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoDaLista; i++){
   
   // Pego o resto da divisão por 2
   int restoDivisao = lista[i] % 2;
   

   if(restoDivisao == 1){ //Se for igual a 1 significa que é um número ímpar

      // Código para adicionar o número na lista de valores ímpares

   } else {

      // Código para adicionar o número na lista de valores pares

   }

}
```

Comment: Nesse código que você colocou, você está trabalhando com vetores. No código que estou tentando fazer estou trabalhando com listas dinâmicas.

Comment: A ideia é a mesma, você só precisa adaptar o seu código para a ideia. Percorra a lista dinâmica, acesse o valor dela, divida por 2 e pegue o resto da divisão para testar no if. Não tenho como criar o código completo p você, pois não sei como você estruturou suas classes e como pode acessar e percorrer a lista.

Comment: Esse é o caso. Não estou conseguindo abstrair. Estou trabalhando com ponteiros e não sei como faço para percorrer uma lista dinâmica.

Comment: Eu não manjo muito de C. Mas pelo que vi no seu código, você percorre a lista nesse trecho:

  while(proximo_ponto != NULL){
        printf("Os valores da lista original sao: %d;\n", proximo_ponto->num);
        proximo_ponto = proximo_ponto->proximo;
    }

Comment: A ideia é essa, percorra a lista e ao invés de exibir os valores, divida eles por 2 e pegue o resto da divisão para testar no if.

Comment: em uma lista dinamica. os elementos tem um ponteiro para o endereço do próximo valor, é só fazer isso para percorrer toda sua lista, até chegar no ultimo elemento que não irá ter o ponteiro, será nulo no caso, ai para cada elemento é só jogar no if e separar em outras duas listas..